# After updating from RN 0.69.9 to 0.70.15 and having a successful build, I can not run an IOS app. I have no errors it just closes

Tags: ios, react-native, version, upgrade

I'm doing a step-by-step update of the project, I've already updated it to version 0.70.15, android has been assembled and launched successfully, but iOS is being assembled but does not launches.

It looks like in a video from [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34608).

I have updated the project from RN 0.69.9 to 0.70.15, in android everything is okay, iOS builds successfully but it closes immediately.

this is my package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "name": "______",
  "homepage": "______",
  "description": "____",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start_localhost": "npm run start",
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "buildAndroid": "fastlane android beta",
    "buildIos": "fastlane ios beta"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@draftbit/maps": "~46.11.0",
    "@draftbit/ui": "46.9.2",
    "@expo/dev-server": "0.1.120",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.0",
    "@mediapipe/pose": "^0.5.1675469404",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.5",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.2.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.5.12",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "6.6.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "6.3.21",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "1.3.1",
    "@shopify/mime-types": "^2.1.0",
    "expo": "47.0.10",
    "expo-asset": "~8.7.0",
    "expo-auth-session": "~3.8.0",
    "expo-av": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-blur": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-camera": "~12.5.0",
    "expo-constants": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-crypto": "~12.0.0",
    "expo-device": "5.0.0",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.1.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-gl": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-linking": "~3.3.1",
    "expo-location": "~15.0.1",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.0.0",
    "expo-modules-core": "1.1.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.17.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-print": "~12.0.0",
    "expo-random": "~13.0.0",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-sharing": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.17.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.0.0",
    "pdf-lib": "^1.17.1",
    "plotly.js": "2.14.0",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-fetch-hook": "1.9.5",
    "react-native": "0.70.15",
    "react-native-auth0": "2.17.4",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "5.4.6",
    "react-native-fs": "2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.15.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.9.5",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-plotly": "6.0.0",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-typography": "1.4.1",
    "react-native-view-shot": "3.4.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.9",
    "react-native-web-swiper": "^2.2.3",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.0",
    "react-plotly.js": "2.6.0",
    "react-query": "3.39.3",
    "react-request": "^3.2.0",
    "victory": "^36.9.1",
    "victory-native": "^36.9.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-native-web": "0.18.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.18.6"
  }
}
```

I have added a hermes to an

```
xcode > build phases > Link binary with Libraries
```

and it has not helped me.